# How to execute command using Tibco BW

Tags: linux, tibco, tibco-business-works

How do I run a shell script file with an input parameter like `./flows.sh suspend` and print the the result to a file using tibco bw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create a process with the palette.

> Palette External Command

The configuration for the new process  should be the next:

INPUT

1. command `./flows.sh suspend`.
2. workingDirectory:*The working directory for the command process.
   If workingDirectory is not specified, the command process inherits its working directory from the process engine.*
   [Image Input example external command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhMYM.jpg)

Configuration

- Output Filename: *Name and location of the file for storing any output or errors produced by the command. If this field is blank, no output file is created.[Image Configuration example external command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBX41.jpg)*